# How to initialize Crashlytics in Fabric.io?

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Looking for some help. I just upgraded my android app to fabric and now the app gives an error on this line:

`Crashlytics.start(getApplicationContext());`

`Gradle: error: cannot find symbol method start(Context)`

I tried commenting out that line, but then the crashes are not getting logged. How do I initialize Crashlytics in the new fabric framework? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Fabric injected this line of code in the launcher activity without deleting the earlier code from the application file. Hence all the confusion. Delete this line from your ptoject: Crashlytics.start(getApplicationContext()); to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Since Crashlytics is now part of Fabric the initialization process has changed, but is still simple. Instead of using `Crashlytics.start()` you should now use, but in the **Application creation**:

```
public class App extends Application {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }

    ...

}
```

For a more richer example, see how Cannonball canonical sample app is doing:

```
public class App extends Application {

    ...

    private TwitterAuthConfig authConfig;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(BuildConfig.CONSUMER_KEY, BuildConfig.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Twitter(authConfig), new MoPub());
    }

    ...

}
```

This code is available at: https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/fabric/samples/cannonball/App.java#L96-L98

Comment: Where did you get this information? Found nothing about it in the official documentation.

Comment: @akhyar probably the cannonball sample app that was revealed in the Twitter conference where they announced Fabric

Comment: Can I later (after Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); call) use smth like this: Crashlytics.setString("key", "value");

???

Comment: @Luis Cipriani Can you help me to resolve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126132/could-not-install-digits-kit-in-eclipse-using-fabric-plugin

Comment: Do i have to add Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()) inside evry activity's oncreate method ??

Comment: Do you know please why the active session is always null in my case? This is how I check the session:     TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession(); and Fabric is initialized like that:     TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(twitterKey, twitterSecretKey);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

Comment: @Luis Cipriani,can you tell me if we include Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); inside application class do we still need to add Fabrid.with() in every Activity?

Answer (score 2):

In latest version init is done automatically by ContentProvider
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

```
 import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics

// ...

// Explicit initialization of Crashlytics is no longer required.

// OPTIONAL: If crash reporting has been explicitly disabled previously, add:
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```