# How to show a Dialog after crash by using Crashlytics?

Tags: android, dialog, crashlytics

How to show a Dialog after crash by using Crashlytics.

for example: after crash I need open a dialog where user will put any comment(note) how he did that crash.

Is any option in Crashlytics?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, definitely. It's also extremely easy.

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().setListener(new CrashlyticsListener() {
  @Override
  public void crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution() {
    // now it's the right time to show the dialog
  }
});
Crashlytics.start(context);
```

**EDIT (Deprecated as of July 2015)**

If you're using the new Fabric integration, the code is slightly different ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539044)). It should look like this:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
Crashlytics.getInstance().setListener(new CrashlyticsListener() {
  @Override
  public void crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution() {
    // now it's the right time to show the dialog
  }
});
```

**EDIT 2 (The latest Fabric SDKs have deprecated the setMethods)**

```
final CrashlyticsListener listener = new CrashlyticsListener() {
            @Override
            public void crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution(){
                  // now it's the right time to show the dialog
            }
        };

final CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore
                                  .Builder()
                                  .listener(listener)
                                  .build();

Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());
```

---

To test your integration, you can simply call `Crashlytics.getInstance().crash()`. Simple but handy.

Comment: Where should I add it? In Application class?

Comment: No any method Crashlytics.start(this);

Comment: You need to pass a `Context` to the `start()` method.

Comment: Crashlytics haven't method start();

Comment: Yes, it does. It is the only way of initializing the SDK. There are two, in fact:  `start(Context context)` and `start(Context context, float delay)`. If you don't see them, then you have some issues in using the Crashlytics plugin.

Comment: previously I add this by this tutorial

Comment: plugin version 2.1.0 doesn't have method Crashlytics.start(Context context);

Comment: I am running the 2.4.0 version, but 2.1.0 have it as well. What other methods do you see?

Comment: See on this png https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzg--_QQ214sVHZOVHpYenptZWc/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Oh, I see now. You're using the Fabric-integrated version of Crashlytics. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Does this occur right when the crash occurs? The name of the functions suggests it doesn't. Is there a way to have a callback for when the crash occurs? I'd like to add some information about the crash and device right when the crash occurs (available heap-memory, activity stack,...) .

Comment: @androiddeveloper Crashlytics sends the crashes on the next startup. You can use custom logging/keys with crashlytics. They will be visible together with the stacktrace. https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html?#custom-logging

Comment: Interesting. How do you know this? What happens if there is a crash and the user has uninstalled the app because of this? Why can't they send the crash information right away (using maybe a second OS-process) ?

Comment: Is this listener called before or after the crash? Can I provide some runtime monitoring data when the crash happens, before the fabric sends the crash report?