# How to run code before Crashlytics submits the log?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I'm looking for a way to add some custom keys to the crash log before it was submitted by Crashlytics. There's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256595/how-to-have-a-callback-for-when-a-crash-occurred-while-using-crashlytics-sdk) for Android. Is it possible to do the same on iOS?

Comment: Your link (with text "enter link description here") is not working, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you posted is to set a custom key/value when there is an uncaught exception.

[Uncaught Error/Exception Handling in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737880/uncaught-error-exception-handling-in-swift)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios

Check these two links.